# How to post form data to Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-apps-script

What is the best/easiest way to post form data from my HTML page to my GAS script?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON(SCRIPT_URL+"?callback=?", { method:"addRow"}, function (data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data)); }); 
});
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON(SCRIPT_URL+"?callback=?", {
      method:"addRow"},
              function (data) { 
                alert(JSON.stringify(data)); 
              });
  });

I'm getting a 404 (OK) error

Comment: Lppk at the docs for doPost/doGet. Look at contentService. Come back with code and we'll help.

Comment: Second attempt, but now getting: Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
My permissions are all public

`function writeToSpreadSheet(postData,callBack){
  $.post(scripturl,postData,function(resp){
   callBack(resp);
 });
}`

Comment: check out the answer to the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888364/get-form-input-text-value-to-insert-in-a-google-spreadsheet/27888908#27888908

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Apps Script HTML Service, you can use `google.script.run`.

[Google Documentation - Client-side API - call server-side Apps Script functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

From a app or site outside of Google, make an HTTP Request to the Apps Script URL.