# Get value of selected radio button Google Html Service

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the selected radio button and push it into another script via html service. However I do not know how to push the selected radio button in google script.

**Index.html**

```
<div>
<?
var attrs = getAllDrawings();
for(i=0; i<attrs.length;i++){
?>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="Drawing" Value= "<?= attrs[i] ?> "> <?= attrs[i] ?> <br>
<? } ?>   

<input type="submit" value="submit"
onclick="google.script.run.getDrawing(result)" />   

<input type="button" value="Close"
onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
</div>
```

What do I use instead of **result** in `google.script.run.getDrawing(result)` so I can run a function based on it

```
function getDrawing(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
}
```

I am creating an html template with a list of files in a folder. The user then selects the needed file, and I need to return the URL for that file to the user. However I do not know how to return the file that the user has selected.
So I need to get the selected radio button value. For example if radios are *Spreadsheet1*, *Spreadsheet2*, *Spreadsheet3* and *Spreadsheet4* and **3rd** one was selected which is *Spreadsheet3* how can I run `getDrawing("Spreadsheet3")`.

Mu problem is similar to this [SO problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672545/google-sheets-script-get-value-from-radio-button-currently-undefined), but I am using HTML instead of UIApp.

**Edit:**

This is how I call **Index.html**

```
function demoHtmlServices() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
  ss.show(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the result of your radio buttons (or any other `input` element) via HTML, without needing to write any additional Google Apps Script code. You need to have the elements inside a named element, and can then navigate to them beginning at `document`. For example, `document.drawings.Drawing.value` will show the value of the `Drawing` radio buttons of the `drawings` form.

You can leave the `submit` button outside of the `form` element that contains the `input` elements you want to access.

```html
<form id="drawings" name="drawings">
<?
var attrs = getAllDrawings();
for(i=0; i<attrs.length;i++){
?>
<input type="radio" name="Drawing" value= "<?= attrs[i] ?>"> <?= attrs[i] ?> <br>
<? } ?>   
</form>

<input type="submit" value="submit"
onclick="google.script.run.getDrawing(document.drawings.Drawing.value)" />   

<input type="button" value="Close"
onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the form(html template) responses, you can use the [withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withSuccessHandler(Function)) and pass the form values this way:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" 
 onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(DataSaved).processForm(this.form)"/>
```

DataSaved is a script function to display a success message. Also processForm is a Apps script function to work with the form responses. You can check this [page](https://plus.google.com/+KathrynvanNieuwkerk/posts/dNxkPDrFZB8?e=-RedirectToSandbox) and this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888364/get-form-input-text-value-to-insert-in-a-google-spreadsheet) for more details on how you can achieve this. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for